# mat-table show colspan and rowspan conditionally inside *ngFor loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angular, angular-material

I want to set rowspan and colspan conditionally so basically want to set first column having rowspan of 2 and other of colspan of 2 inside ngFor

```
    <ng-container matColumnDef="header-row-first-group">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [style.text-align]="center" [attr.rowspan]="2">
            No
        </th>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="header-row-sec-group">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [style.text-align]="center" [attr.colspan]="2">
            group 1
        </th>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="header-row-third-group">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [style.text-align]="center" [attr.colspan]="2">
            group 2
        </th>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="header-row-forth-group">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [style.text-align]="center" [attr.colspan]="2">
            group 3
        </th>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="header-row-fifth-group">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [style.text-align]="center" [attr.colspan]="2">
            group 4
        </th>
    </ng-container>
```

Have changed to

```
 <ng-container matColumnDef="header-row-{{i}}-group" *ngFor="let grouping of groupArr; let i = index">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [style.text-align]="center" [attr.colspan]="2">
          {{grouping}}
        </mat-header-cell>
 </ng-container>
```

but i want to set [attr.rowspan]="2" for first column and let others have [attr.colspan]="2".
How can i achieve this I'm using angular material mat-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `*ngFor`'s [local variable](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables) `first`. It is boolean containing `true` for the first item of the iteration and `false` for others.

```html
<ng-container 
  matColumnDef="header-row-{{i}}-group" 
  *ngFor="let grouping of groupArr; let i=index; let f=first"
>
  <ng-container *ngIf="f; else colSpan">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [style.text-align]="center" [attr.rowspan]="2">
      {{grouping}}
    </mat-header-cell>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-template #colSpan>
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [style.text-align]="center" [attr.colspan]="2">
      {{grouping}}
    </mat-header-cell>
  </ng-template>
</ng-container>
```

Edit: `<ng-container>` -> `<ng-template>`

Comment: @Micheal D I received an  ERROR Error: ngIfElse must be a TemplateRef, but received '[object Comment]'

Comment: <ng-template #colSpan>
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [style.text-align]="center" [attr.colspan]="2">
      {{grouping}}
    </mat-header-cell>
  </ng-template> worked for me!!

Comment: Yes I've changed the answer as well. The `else` block with the template ref must be explicitly an `<ng-template>`.